# how to add other columns to the joinTable in a Many To Many relationship in hibernate JPA?

Tags: database, jpa, many-to-many

I have two entities User and File . a File can be shared with many users and a user can receive many files . So it's a Many To Many relationship between the two entities .

**in the User class :**

```
 @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "receiver_shared",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name =  "user_id", 
                               insertable =false, updatable = false),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name ="file_id",   
                                     insertable = false, updatable = false))
         private List<File> receivedfiles;
```

**in the File class :**

```
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "receivedfiles")
        private List<User> receivers;
```

My problem is that I want to save the shareTime and to assign permissions when  a file is shared with a user . I mean file 1 can be shared with user 1 with permissions read and write and it's shared with user 2 with permission read Only .

I'm new to JPA . What I was thinking about is that the **receiver_shared** Table must contain a permission column and shareTime column .

**how to do this  ?**

**Update :**

as JB Nizet suggested  I've created a new Share entity .

I've added this to my File Class

```
@OneToMany (mappedBy = "sharedFile",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Share> shares = new ArrayList<Share>();
```

I've added this to my User Class

```
@OneToMany (mappedBy = "receiver",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Share> receivedfiles = new ArrayList<Share>();
```

In my Share Class I have added a column shareTime , a column permission and :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "receiver_id")
    private User receiver;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "file_id")
    private File sharedFile;
```

I tested my configuration with JUnit

```
User receiver=userRepository.findOne((long)2);
File toshare=fileRepository.findOne((long)2);
Share s=new Share(toshare,receiver,1,new Timestamp(newDate().getTime()));
shareRepository.save(s);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the join table contains additional functional information, it's not a join table anymore, and it must be mapped as an entity.

So you'll have a one-to-many between User and Share, and a one-to-many between File and Share.

Comment: when I try to save a new Share I get this error , org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: entities.User;

check my update

Comment: Remove cascade = ALL from your ManyToOne. That doesn't make sense. You don't want a user and a file to be deleted from the database when you delete a file. You should also do your job inside a single transaction, instead of using 3 different transactions.

Comment: thank you so much , and sorry for my questions it's because I'm self learning